# Pass remark from user as string to java bean

Tags: java, javascript, jsf

I need to accept a remark from the user on button click and pass it as a string to the managed bean behind.
This is what I have on the jsp page-

```
    <h:column>
            <button onclick="myFunction();">
                <h:commandLink value="Forward" action="#{add_leave.Forward()}">
                <f:param name="emp_id2" value="#{leave_requests.emp_id}" />
                <f:param name="request_id2" value="#{leave_requests.request_id}" />

                </h:commandLink>
            </button>
        </h:column>
```

This is the javascript function-

```
function myFunction()
{
    var x;
    var reason=prompt("Please enter your reason:","Reason");
    x=reason;

}
```

I need this reason variable here in the function of my bean AddNewLeave.java -

```
public void Forward()
{
    ...
    ...
    String reasonStr;
}
```

How do I do it? Also, is there any other simpler way i could have employed to get a remark from user to be used elsewhere? I'm a newbie at web application programming and trying to learn things as and when I require'em.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using `<h:inputHidden>` to send the value to your bean automatically on form submit:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:inputHidden id="remark" value="#{bean.remark}" />
    ...
</h:form>
```

This way, once you update the hidden input's value via JavaScript and will submit form afterwards, you'll end up with the bean property preset for you by JSF.

The JS snippet could be:

```
document.getElementById('form:remark').value = remark;
```

Of course, the same functionality could be obtained by using plain `<input type="hidden">`, but in that case you'd have to find the remark string in request parameter map.